# nvd3.js coloring specific bars, tooptips and xAxis labels

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I draw a multiBarChart using nvd3.js.

xAxis shows a date and i need to change the color of saturday's and sunday's bars, tooltips and xAxis labels.

I can add additional parameter to my json, such as:

```
{ x: someX, y: someY, series: 0, isHoliday: true }
```

But, for example, in tooltipContent callback function I can't access to json element, because it has such arguments - key, x, y, e, graph.

In tickFormat callback function I also can't access to json element, because first argument is x value and the second is index.

this is HighCharts example - https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf1rx5axl5h5wb2/2013-09-29_2216.png

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

The additional attributes can be accessed through the e.point property.

For instance, for the tooltip part, you'd can have code like this:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
            .options({
                showXAxis: true,
                showYAxis: true,
                transitionDuration: 250

            }).tooltip(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                if (e.point.isHoliday) {
                  //your custom code here
                }
            }
```

Here are a couple of other options for the other two questions:

For changing the colour of the bars, you could do something like this:

```
    d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar")
            .style("fill-opacity", function (d, i) { //d is the data bound to the svg element
               //Used opacity here but anything can be changed
                return d.isHoliday ? .8 : .6; 
            })
```

For the label part, I opted for the code below instead of the tickFormat callback, as I needed more control over the label.

```
d3.select('.nv-x.nv-axis > g').selectAll('g').selectAll('text')
            .attr('transform', function (d, i, j) {
                return d.isHoliday ? 'translate (0, 15)' : ''; //Lowers the label text for the holiday instances
            })
            .attr('class', function (d, i, j) {
                return d.isHoliday ? 'holiday-graph-legend' : 'default-graph-legend'; 
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to do this in NVD3. You basically have two options.

- You can take the generated SVG and modify it. So you would select the generated bars, then subselect the relevant ones and change them accordingly. This is quite clumsy though; for a start you would need to wait until all the content has been generated before doing that.
- You could modify the NVD3 source to do what you want.

I would recommend the second option. You're much more flexible and can do exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you tell me where in the code e object is generated? Now I'm trying to build pieChart and I need key labels, but in tooltip I want to use percents, like so - "Visits: 42 (55%)". I find in pie.js file where percent for each slice is calculated, but I don't know how to pass it to the tooltip function. I think the easiest way is to add corresponding field to e object, which can be accessed inside tooltip function callback. Thanks again.

Comment: `e` corresponds to one of the data items you bind. You can add any attributes to that and access them later.

Comment: e.point corresponds to data point. Yes, I can add any attrs to it, but I don't want to calculate percents from values by myself, if nvd3 already does it. But I don't find, how I can access to percent value inside tooltip func. e object doesn't content such field.

Comment: You can add it to the original data when calculating the percentages.

Comment: You can calculate percentage and attach it to d. Then in your pie chart call, you just return already calculated percentage. Here's a d3 example with tooltip on barchart: http://vida.io/documents/F3Ehr3qqeK28P22wn